# how to import a formatted text file into mysql database

Tags: mysql

sing the Mac terminal, how could you populate a mysql database when the text file has a format like this.

```
00000,1284
00001,2081
```

I have created the database table to reflect that data however I am not sure on how to import a text file with this type of format..

This is what I am trying to use right now but its not working

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'Developer/Shared Files/NIS.txt INTO TABLE nisC FIRLDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Comment: syntax was wrong, correct syntax was given below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the statement as below

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'Developer/Shared Files/NIS.txt' INTO TABLE nisC (field1, field2);
```

Comment: Think you might need the `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` to use commas instead of tabs.

Comment: I'm getting this error when using your code// ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of '/usr/local/mysql/data/Developer/Shared Files/NIS.txt'

Comment: nothing I am doing is working... I have tried so many different combinations and nothing seems to work.

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT!!!! annoying but the start of that queriy has to be **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE** and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: [LOCAL]: This option declares that the target INFILE must reside on the client side. If omitted,the target INFILE must reside on the same server hosting the MySQL database. When LOCAL is used, the path to the file can be either absolute or relative according to the present location.When omitted, the path can be absolute, local, or, if not present, assumed to reside in MySQL’s designated database directory or in the presently chosen database directory.

Comment: @C.Johns: I always wondered why I had to put my input file in /tmp with world access (777). That explains... (without LOCAL, the client tells the server to get the input file, so makes sense not to allow that unless you have world access). Thanks !