# How to get a (text) file into a mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I am trying to load a couple of JS libraries into a MySQL table

```
create table JSlib (
  ID int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255),
  file TEXT
);
```

I have tried

```
insert into JSlib (name, file) values ('Full', LOAD_FILE('C:\Apache24\htdocs\ia\Full.js'));
```

But this fails because the MySQL database is a remote (AWS) instance

I also saw this post that's related: [how to import a formatted text file into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462728/how-to-import-a-formatted-text-file-into-mysql-database)

But my files are JavaScript files, not structures text. I know I could just copy the text from the file, but this is problematic given all of the single and double quotes in my JavaScript.

Maybe I could create a dummy php page to select and load the file through the browser and add it to the DB that way... Is that the best way?

Comment: Fails with what error?

Comment: Where is the code running? I am guessing it is not in C:\Apache24\htdocs

Comment: @RiggsFolly no error message. Just no file contents inserted (field value is null)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am running the sql in mySQLWorkbench

Comment: LOAD_FILE you need FILE privilege plus the file needs to be in a safe directory  which the setting secure_file_priv controls

Comment: Using a secure_file_priv which include to a to large number of directories or not set can be trouble.. Becuase you should load in every file.. Also with SELECT ... OUTFILE you could generate a backdoor shell if MySQL is allowed to make a file under public accessable url so look out..

Comment: I think there are ways to do that, you also can store complicated html mixed javascript codes in your database. Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322569/whats-the-best-way-to-store-html-code-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then go ahead an insert your files as string in a TEXT column. Example:

```
/* Assuming $conn is defined, else see PHP DOCS */
// Change `javascript` to your column and "js/jquery.js" to the location of your file.
// NOTE: Your column should be a TEXT field, no limitation in length.
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `javascript` (codesnippet) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $codesnippet);
$codesnippet = file_get_contents( "js/jquery.js" );
$stmt->execute();
```

Another way would be to link your files on the server in your database for replication, if needed.

Answer (score -1):

if your columns in file separated by ',' :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Apache24\htdocs\ia\Full.js' 
INTO table JSlib FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','(name, file);
```

Comment: @KerimYagmurcu Yes, this is what I want